Avoiding Race Conditions between multiple Spark Structured Streaming queries
I have a Spark Job that spawns multiple structured streaming queries that read from their own kafka topics and write to a common kafka topic while using Avro.
I use spark-avro and https://github.com/AbsaOSS/ABRiS for writing in to_avro format after doing a schema unionByName and do union of the common kafka topic's schema on the schema registry.
The problem is when multiple streaming queries try to write the schema on the schema registry, some queries fail with the error:
Cannot find 'field_1'

Is there a way I can use locks or something so that only one streaming query can push schema to the schema registry to avoid this inconsistency and the race condition?

Without a sample of your code and data, it's challenging to provide a precise solution. However, such errors often arise when the actual data schemas don't match your expectations. I suggest investigating schema compatibility checks and schema evolution rules. It's also beneficial to research best practices for handling multiple incoming data streams. Have you considered registering each source's schema individually before performing the union operation? Did you check one-by-one which stream is not matching?
